# Is it possible to designate the login.php as homepage?

Tags: login, homepage

Is it possible to designate the login.php as homepage AND would I be able to keep the url as "DOMAIN.COM"?

Is there any reason why this would not be recommended?

Comment: You can create custom login page and set it as home page.

Comment: There are a lot of plugins that allow you to customize your login page. It would be easier for me to designate the page I have already customized...if possible.

Comment: I have no skill in CSS, so creating a new template from scratch would probably yield results that would leave a lot to desired.

Comment: I think the reason there isn't a solution readily out there, is because the process of logging in is usually a means to an end, and people don't want to use the prime real-estate of the homepage dedicated to the login. If all your users must be logged in, it makes sense to have that be a page the homepage redirects to if the user isn't logged in, and then show what you want to show on the homepage to the user when they are logged in.